# How to multiply specific value in pandas dataframe according to condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as

```
    Element Code    Item Code   Item    Year    Unit    Value
0   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2000-2002   g/capita/day    16.3
1   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2001-2003   g/capita/day    16.0
2   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2002-2004   g/capita/day    15.7
3   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2003-2005   g/capita/day    16.0
4   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2004-2006   g/capita/day    15.7
5   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2005-2007   g/capita/day    15.3
6   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2006-2008   g/capita/day    15.3
7   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2007-2009   g/capita/day    16.0
8   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2008-2010   g/capita/day    16.3
9   6123    21014   Average protein supply  2009-2011   g/capita/day    16.0
10  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2010-2012   g/capita/day    15.7
11  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2011-2013   g/capita/day    15.3
12  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2012-2014   g/capita/day    14.6
13  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2013-2015   g/capita/day    13.3
14  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2014-2016   g/capita/day    12.3
15  6123    21014   Average protein supply  2015-2017   g/capita/day    12.3
16  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2000-2002   millions    2.4
17  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2001-2003   millions    2.4
18  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2002-2004   millions    2.2
19  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2003-2005   millions    2.1
20  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2004-2006   millions    1.9
21  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2005-2007   millions    1.8
22  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2006-2008   millions    1.5

23  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2007-2009   millions    1.3
24  6132    210011  People Undernourished   2008-2010   millions    1.2
```

Now, I want to multiply the values in "million" of the Unit Column. How should I do that, I tried

```
df1["Value"] = df1["Value"].apply(lambda x: x*1000000 if df1["Unit"]=="millions" else False)
```

but It gave an error as

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated !!

Comment: `df.loc[df['Unit']=='millions','Value'] *=1000000`

Comment: if not 'millions' in unit, you want False in the column Value or you want to keep the original value?

Comment: Thanks so much @Chris,

Comment: @Ben.T, No  I wanted to multiply the value in Value columns only if their Unit were in millions